# Unable to chdir or not a Git archive

Tags: git

I have created a remote bare repository:

```
cd ~
mkdir -p git/foto-fiori.git
cd git/foto-fiori.git
git init --bare
```

Then I added it:

```
git remote add origin collimarco@foto-fiori.com:/home/collimarco/git/foto-fiori.git
```

I get:

```
$ git push
fatal: '/home/collimarco/git/foto-fiori.git': unable to chdir or not a git archive
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I also tried to use ~/git/foto-fiori.git but is the same...

I'm desperate: what should I try to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamhost was migrating to other servers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `:` after the hostname:

```
git add origin collimarco@foto-fiori.com:/home/collimarco/git/foto-fiori.git
```

That should also enable you to skip the home directory, i.e. you could say:

```
git add origin collimarco@foto-fiori.com:git/foto-fiori.git
```

Comment: I deleted old config and typed git remote add origin collimarco@foto-fiori.com:git/foto-fiori.git
But I still get that error :(

Answer (score 1):

First step: Check that `ssh -vvv collimarco@foto-fitori.com` works with publickey authentication. You might want to have a look at Gitosis- it simplifies the process of hosting Git repositories easily and securely [http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way].

Answer (score 1):

I've got exactly the same error, it was because I placed the remote (bare) directory elsewhere. If anybody gets this message, I recommend to simply check that the remote dir exists where it really should. 
I expect (from the previous post from collimarco) that it was the same problem.